# Setting XAML at runtime?

Tags: xaml

Can I dynamically create an XAML and pop it into my app? How would it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it's pretty simple:

```
XmlReader tXml = XmlReader.Create(myXamlString);
UIElement MyElement = (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(tXml);
```

Then you can do what you like with it.

Answer (score 1):

A few articles on dynamic XAML generation:

- [Dynamic XAML to display XML](http://blogs.msdn.com/calvin_hsia/archive/2007/12/06/6684376.aspx)
- [Dynamic XAML with the presentation model pattern](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/35135)